# created custom Object is null (JPA Repository)

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot

I want to create a Node object and despite the program compiling, when I call *Node node = new Node()* , the object created is null and nothign is added to the database.

I don't understand where the error lies exactly

this is my Node class :
@Entity

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Node  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Node parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade =  { CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<Node> children;

}
```

Comment: @Kayaman Node rootNode = new Node(); i already wrote it in my original post, it's just 1 line

Comment: @Kayaman LOL. i'm literally cringing at my post right now, I realized my mistake and i'm very sorry for sounding silly

Comment: Happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 0):

I realized i forgot to implement the JPA repository. Yikes